# How to change a Javascript character-remaining counter, with an onClick?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea

Hello :) I have an HTML text area with a Javascript character counter. I want the remaining character count to be reduced by 23 characters when someone clicks the "Browse" button to add media to the text area they are writing.  I'm using PHP too.  How can I do it? :)

Here is the HTML

```
    <form id="form" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div>
            <label for="message2">Type your message</label>
            <textarea ID="message2" onkeyup="textCounter(this,'counter',140);" name="status"></textarea>
            Add Picture<input type="file" name="image" /><br />
            <input class="button" type="submit" value="Tweet" /><br />
        </div>
    </form>
```

And the Jquery

```
   <script>
$(document).ready(function(){   

    $("#message2").charCount({
        allowed: 140,       
        warning: 10,
        counterText: ''
    });
});
```

And the CharCount.js

```
    (function($) {

$.fn.charCount = function(options){

    // default configuration properties
    var defaults = {    
        allowed: 140,       
        warning: 25,
        css: 'counter',
        counterElement: 'span',
        cssWarning: 'warning',
        cssExceeded: 'exceeded',
        counterText: ''
    }; 

    var options = $.extend(defaults, options); 

    function calculate(obj){
        var count = $(obj).val().length;
        var available = options.allowed - count;
        if(available <= options.warning && available >= 0){
            $(obj).next().addClass(options.cssWarning);
        } else {
            $(obj).next().removeClass(options.cssWarning);
        }
        if(available < 0){
            $(obj).next().addClass(options.cssExceeded);
        } else {
            $(obj).next().removeClass(options.cssExceeded);
        }
        $(obj).next().html(options.counterText + available);
    };

    this.each(function() {              
        $(this).after('<'+ options.counterElement +' class="' + options.css + '">'+ options.counterText +'</'+ options.counterElement +'>');
        calculate(this);
        $(this).keyup(function(){calculate(this)});
        $(this).change(function(){calculate(this)});
    });

};
```

})(jQuery);

Comment: `.charCount` is not a standard jQuery extension.  What extension are you using?  Is it homegrown, or standard?  Going to be tough to answer your question (short of re-writing it) without that information.

Comment: ahh my bad, pasted the code from a larger page and missed adding it, sorry adding now.

Answer (score 1):

It would be ideal to rewrite charCount to use an attribute of the object to determine the max length, something like data-maxlength="140" (can reference using $(obj).data("maxlength") in jquery).

Then, you can adjust the length dynamically.  I don't see the browse button in your code, so update the selector as needed.

```
$("browse").click(function() {
    $("#message2").data("maxlength", 116).change();
    // calling change() triggers recalc of length
});
```

Comment: I agree with this. Alternatively, you could write a `.setAllowed()` method.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do something like this.

```
   $(document).ready(showCounter);
   $('#form input[type:submit]').on('click', function(){
      allowed - 23;
   }, false);

   var allowed = 140;

   var showCounter = function(){
      $(".counter").remove();
      $("#message2").charCount({
          allowed: allowed,       
          warning: 10,
          counterText: ''
      });
   };
```

Comment: Because charCount adds the listeners to the object, if you call it multiple times, you should add code to clear the old listeners. Edit: You accounted for that by externalizing the allowed variable :-)